# Share application ios?

Tags: ios

I do not know exactly is called in iOS terms.
Well I have a share button in my app. On the click of the button I want to open a list of installed apps through which I can share my app store link.

For eg: Through msg, email, whatsapp, facebook etc.

The app store link will be string with some message attached to it.

For eg: Download the latest : some URL or app store URL

Comment: `UIDocumentInteractionController`? Or maybe `UIActivityViewController`?

Comment: I just need to send a string to other apps.

Comment: Thnx @maddy exactly what i needed to search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://www.codingexplorer.com/add-sharing-to-your-app-via-uiactivityviewcontroller/) solves my problem.

Add the following code on your button press:

```
NSString *textToShare = @"Guys, Check this website";
NSURL *myWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.9gag.com/"]; //any URL

NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare, myWebsite];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                               UIActivityTypePrint,
                               UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                               UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```